# Removing Punctuation from a String and Appending it to a List in Python

Tags: python, string, list, punctuation

I'm a python learner. Was trying to remove punctuations from a list of strings and create a new list but failing.

```
string_list = ['Jingle Bells.', "Donkey Kong's", "Jumping Jehosophat;"]
strings_modified = []
for s in string_list:
    strings_modified.append.str(s).translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

The error I receive is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-316-5c979f5c8af8> in <module>()
      2 strings_modified = []
      3 for s in string_list:
----> 4     strings_modified.append.str(s).translate(None, string.punctuation)

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: need brackets after append and no need to convert to string:   strings_modified.append(s.translate(None, string.punctuation))

Comment: Don't use `append.str(s)` use `append(str(s))`

Comment: the problem is that my type is unicode. `type(string_list[0])` is `unicode` . If I don;t use str i get this error: `TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`. So I end up using `str(s)`.  But this creates another set of problems down the line. When I try doing `for sm in strings_modified:
        strings_modified.append(sm.replace(" ", "+"))` , python just hangs . . .

Comment: @PrestonHager Is right. It still converts it to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments to original post there's a typo in string

```
strings_modified.append.str(s)
```

it must be

```
strings_modified.append(str(s))
```

But since signature of `translate` method has been changed in Python 3, new version can look like:

```
trans_dict = {ord(i):None for i in string.punctuation}

for s in string_list:
    strings_modified.append(s.translate(trans_dict))
```

Or, using list comprehension (more Pythonic)

```
strings_modified = [s.translate(trans_dict) for s in string_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo on your code:

```
strings_modified.append.str(s).translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

that is the error you are getting, you are trying to call a function named str from a 'builtin_function_or_method' called append, which does not have that method because it doesn't work that way!

Your code should (probably depending on your context) be:

```
strings_modified.append(str(s).translate(None, string.punctuation))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is very complicated. If we have a function `fcn` that does the removing, we can use Python's list comprehensions to generate the output.

Something like: `[fcn(s) for s in string_list]`. Now you just have to write `fcn`.

Since you already know about translate, we can write this as

```
[s.translate(None, string.punctuation) for s in string_list]
```